# Using jQuery to show fields based on user input

Tags: javascript, forms, google-forms

I have created a Google Form that will be used for guests to RSVP to an event. Instead of making each person RSVP individually, I would like the form to allow someone to select the number of people who will be coming in their party, and fill out the details.

The form has 8 fieldsets with each containing:

- A text field for name
- a radio button for chicken/steak/vegetarian

What I would like to do is have a select option that asks "How many people will be in your party" and when they select that number, the appropriate number of fieldsets will appear.

I know how to show/hide with jQuery, but not based on a number from a select.

Comment: This sounds like a job for angular.js :).  In other words, the value of the selected option will be data-bound to the number of list items.

Comment: The link you posted doesn't go to a specific fiddle